# How to filter a sf object by latitude?

Tags: r, r-sf

## Data

I have a shapefile for Ontario province boundary that I read as follows:

```
library(sf)
library(here)
ontario <- sf::st_read(here::here("data", "messy_data", "Ontario.shp"), quiet = TRUE) %>%
  st_transform(4326)
```

It can be plotted as follows:

[image]

## Question

I want to keep the `ontario` data only for `latitude < 51`. But since it is a `sf` object, `dplyr::filter(latitude < 51)` doesn't work. I know that I can extract the coordinates with `st_coordinates()`, but how can I join them back to the data to filter out the higher altitude?
Alternatively, is there any function in `sf` that I could use to do the filter? I looked into the help but couldn't find anything relevant so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep"? Make a new shape that crops the feature at 51N? It would help if you could make a reproducible example with some common data and not use `here`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's get Canada from the GADM data:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
cdn = getData("GADM",country="can",level=1)
```

this should be Ontario:

```
ont = cdn[9,]
ont$NAME_1
```

convert to an `sf` object:

```
ont = st_as_sf(ont)
```

Now to business - crop to 51 degrees north:

```
ont_south = st_crop(ont, xmin=-180, xmax=180, ymin=-90, ymax=51)
plot(ont_south$geometry)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea it was that simple! This is exactly what I was trying to do. The reason for that crop is that I want to interpolate the weather using point data and there's only 1 weather station data available above the latitude of 51 degrees.