# Cropping a shapefile in R

Tags: r, crop, tmap

How can I crop the map (shapefile) more or less as the red square, even just a good nord-est zoom would be good if its easier

I need to merge the cropped map (shapefile) to my dataset afterwards

I am using the tmap and sf packages in R

[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvfbc.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a sf object by latitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546934/how-to-filter-a-sf-object-by-latitude)

Comment: You could create a polygon and then use `st_intersection()`